# How to get the entire path of the selected menus in Angular material Nested menus

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-material

I am new to angular and using the Angular material Nested menu

the code is pretty simple like this

```
<mat-menu #animals="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="vertebrates">Vertebrates</button>
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="invertebrates">Invertebrates</button>
</mat-menu>

<mat-menu #vertebrates="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="fish">Fishes</button>
</mat-menu>

<mat-menu #invertebrates="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Insects</button>
</mat-menu>
```

so we have two menus at the parent level say **vertebrates** and **invertebrates** and sub menus have fish and insects that will open when hovered or clicked on the parent

so when any child item that is the submenu gets clicked I want the entire path like

For Example
One hovers on **vertebrates** and selects the submenu **Fishes** I want to display the entire path like

"vertibrates Fishes"

so if like have any levels of sub menus I want the entire path is it possible in an easy way?

any help is highly appreciated..!!

Comment: It would be better, if you can provide stackblitz reproducing the issue ;)

Comment: here is the example

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-nested-menu-example

Comment: mainly what I want is I need an entire path when one selects the final menu as vertibrates=>fishes=>balaShark

Comment: @Sivakumar Tadisetti I don't think anyone except you can solve this in a most simpler way I became a big fan of yours as your answers are being just simple awesome and perfect for me...!!

Comment: @kushalBaldev Can you please share the solution?