# convert returned Observables to custom class array in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, angular8

Hello folks I will keep my question very simpler by showing code

1. I am using Json placeholder site for the fake rest Api
2. I have a user class Object
3. I want to convert returned Observable to the
   custom class object array.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Users } from './users.model';
    
        @Injectable({
          providedIn: 'root'
        })
        export class UsersService {
        
          private url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
        
          constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
            console.log(this.getUsers());
           }
        
        
          getUsers():Observable<Users[]>{
            return this.http.get<Users[]>(`${this.url}/posts`);
        }
        
        }
```

The above is my service

```
    export class Users {
        email:          string;
        id:             number;
        name:           string;
        phone:          string;
        username:       string;
        
    }
```

above is my class I haven't included all properties

In my typescript file I have code like.

```
constructor(private _usersService:UsersService) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this._usersService.getUsers().subscribe(data=>this.users=data);

    console.log(this.users);
  }
```

Now the things I want is

1. how to convert returned observable in my custom class object?
2. I don't have all the fields so how is it possible to map only those fields which I want?

Hope my question is clear..!!

Comment: please make it a little more clear for me. so your API returns an observable with an array of objects and you want to make changes on those objects and return the array that is modified?

Comment: yes exactly you can hit https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users and it returns the array of json objects the thing I need is  1) I need to convert into my custom object 2)If I dont need all the properties I can be able to map only the some property for example it has geo property but as you can see I dont have it so I can have objects of my own custom class is it possible?

Comment: yes its possible ill write a function for that one min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so this answer takes advantage of map() which is imported from rxjs.

before subscribing we are going to pipe a map() function into the observable stream and then map() each element from that array into a new object that fits our User interface

then we subscribe and the data we get then will be an array that fits our User interface

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this._usersService.getUsers()
    .pipe(map(data => {
      return data.map(item => {
        const user: User = {
          name: item.name,
          email: item.email,
        }
        return user
      })
    }))
    .subscribe(data=>this.users=data);

    console.log(this.users);
  }
```

Comment: did you import map from rxjs like this? import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: ya I need to import all things and just it got solved but ran to other problem for User that you have mentioned can you explain const user: User = {
          name: item.name,
          email: item.email,
        } I am getting "Cannot find name 'User'"

Comment: in typescript we create models that represent how our data is going to look like, however since you don't have a User interface just remove the  ': User'

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below, in the `User` class have a constructor and return `User` while mapping

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class User {
    email: string;
    id: number;
    name: string;
    phone: string;
    username: string;

    constructor( user: User ) {
      Object.assign( this, user );
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<User[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .pipe(
      map( data => {
        return data.map( ( user ) => {
          return new User( {
            email: user['email'],
            id: user['id'],
            name: user['name'],
            phone: user['phone'],
            username: user['username'],
          } );
        } );
      } ),
    )
    .subscribe( (users : User[]) => console.log(users) );
  }
}
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5urjzd)

Comment: Thanks for the solution like I added like this._usersService.getUsers() .pipe(
      map( data => {
        return data.map( ( user ) => {
          return new User( {
            email: user['email'],
            id: user['id'],
            name: user['name'],
            phone: user['phone'],
            username: user['username'],
          } );
        } );
      } ),
    )
    .subscribe( (users : User[]) => console.log(users) ); but I am getting the mapped value that is only Id rest comes undefined can you guide me what I am missing?

Comment: @kushalBaldev how rest comes undefined? in the stackblitz provided it is working fine right!!!

Comment: Can you remove that `pipe()` and just subscribe and then in the subscribe do `console.log(data)` and check what are the values you are getting

Comment: yes It was my mistake I restarted the server anyway thanks..!!! It works like a charm.!!

Comment: I just watched your profile and seems that you have knowledge for the front end so I have already two posts on the angular material part which is still unanswered  can you provide there the solution so I can provide you links of the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646083/how-to-select-the-table-row-in-angular-based-on-the-object/62646407#62646407

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512020/how-to-get-the-entire-path-of-the-selected-menus-in-angular-material-nested-menu